# When to use OrderByCompletion (Jon Skeet) vs Parallel.ForEach with async delegates

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Recently Jon Skeet at NDC London spoke about C# 5 async/await and presented the idea of "***ordering by completion***" a list of async tasks. A link http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time.aspx

I am a bit confused or should I say I am not sure when will this technique be more appropriate to use.

I cannot understand the difference between this and the below example

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<object>();
Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, async item =>
{
  // some pre stuff
  var response = await GetData(item);
  bag.Add(response);
  // some post stuff
}
```

or ***ForEachAsync*** as explained by Stephen Toub - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx

> **EDIT:** Found a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx) from **Stephen Toub** explaining "Ordering by completion" <=> "Processing tasks as they complete". Worth reading. After reading this I could clearly understand the reasons how it works and also when to use this technique.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` already is for multithreading.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Don't use `Parallel.ForEach` to execute `async` code. `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't understand `async`, so your lambda will be turned into `async void`, which won't work correctly (`Parallel.ForEach` will return before all work is done; exceptions won't be handled properly; possibly other issues).
- Use something like `ForEachAsync()` when you have a collection of objects (not `Task`s), you want to perform some `async` action for each of them and the actions should execute in parallel.
- Use `OrderByCompletion()` when you have a collection of `Task`s, you want perform some action (asynchronous or not) for the result of each `Task`, the actions should *not* execute in parallel and you want to execute the actions based on the order in which the `Task`s complete.

Comment: The [ForEachAsync](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) method is documented on Stephen Toub's blog.

Comment: @DanEsparza Yeah, I didn't link to it again, because it's already linked to in the question.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, async item =>
> ```

This is almost certainly not what you want. The delegate has type `Action<T>`, and so the anonymous method is an `async void` method. That means it gets launched, and you have no way of checking its status other than by checking for any of its side effects. In particular, if *anything* goes wrong, you cannot catch and handle the exception.

Assuming nothing goes wrong, though, results will be added to `bag` as they complete. Until anything completes, `bag` will be empty.

In contrast, `OrderByCompletion` returns an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` that *immediately* contains all not-yet-finished tasks. You could `await` the fifth element and continue when any five tasks have completed. This might be useful when, for example, you want to run a large number of tasks and periodically update a form to show the progress.

The third option you gave, `ForEachAsync`, would behave like `ForEach`, except it would do it right, without the problems mentioned above.

Comment: If you look at the versions of `ForEachAsync()` later in the article, they do *not* wait for each task to complete before starting the next.

Comment: @svick Ah, it has multiple different definitions of `ForEachAsync` that don't just differ in implementation details, but also user-visible behaviour. Thanks, I didn't notice that.