# Is it OK to do some async/await inside some .NET Parallel.ForEach() code?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, async-await, parallel.foreach

Given the following code, is it *OK* to do `async/await` inside a `Parallel.ForEach` ?

eg.

```
Parallel.ForEach(names, name =>
{
    // Do some stuff...

    var foo = await GetStuffFrom3rdPartyAsync(name);

    // Do some more stuff, with the foo.
});
```

or is there some gotcha's that I need to be made aware of?

EDIT: No idea if this compiles, btw. Just Pseduo-code .. thinking out loud.

Answer (score 6):

No, It doesn't make sense to combine `async` with `Paralell.Foreach`.

Consider the following example:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    var names = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(x=> "Somename" + x);
    Parallel.ForEach(names, async(name) =>
    {   
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Name {0} completed",name);
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel ForEach completed");
}
```

What output you will expect?

```
Name Somename3 completed
Name Somename8 completed
Name Somename4 completed
...
Parallel ForEach completed
```

That's not what will happen. It will output :

```
Parallel ForEach completed
Name Somename3 completed
Name Somename8 completed
Name Somename4 completed
...
```

Why? Because when `ForEach` hits first `await` the method actually returns, `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't know it is asynchronous and it ran to completion!. Code after `await` runs as continuation on another thread **not** "Paralell processing thread"

[Stephen toub addressed this here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx)

Comment: OKay - so what would you suggest then?

Comment: @Pure.Krome What is the problem you try to solve? With given context it's hard to answer. If waiting is an option you can `Task.Run(async ()=> await Something()).Wait();`

Answer (score 5):

From the name, I'm assuming that `GetStuffFrom3rdPartyAsync` is I/O-bound. The `Parallel` class is specifically for CPU-bound code.

In the asynchronous world, you can start multiple tasks and then (asynchronously) wait for them all to complete using `Task.WhenAll`. Since you're starting with a sequence, it's probably easiest to *project* each element to an asynchronous operation, and then await all of those operations:

```
await Task.WhenAll(names.Select(async name =>
{
  // Do some stuff...
  var foo = await GetStuffFrom3rdPartyAsync(name);
  // Do some more stuff, with the foo.
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

A close alternative might be this:

```
static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, Task> func)
{
    var tasks = data.Select(item => 
        Task.Run(() => func(item)));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

// ... 

ForEach(names, name => GetStuffFrom3rdPartyAsync(name));
```

Ideally, you shouldn't be using a blocking call like `Task.WaitAll`, if you can make the whole chain of methods calls `async`, "all the way down" on the current call stack:

```
var tasks = data.Select(item => 
    Task.Run(() => func(item)));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Furthermore, if you don't do any CPU-bound work inside `GetStuffFrom3rdPartyAsync`, `Task.Run` may be redundant:

```
var tasks = data.Select(item => func(item));
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Sriram Sakthivel there are some problems with using `Parallel.ForEach` with asynchronous lambdas. Steven Toub's `ForEachASync` can do the equivalent. He talks about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478114/when-to-use-orderbycompletion-jon-skeet-vs-parallel-foreach-with-async-delegat), but here is the code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(
            from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
            select Task.Run(async delegate {
                                               using (partition) while (partition.MoveNext()) await body(partition.Current);
            }));
    }
}
```

It uses the `Partitioner` class to create a load balancing partitioner([doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), and allows you to specify how many threads you want to run with the `dop` parameter. to see the difference between it and `Parallel.ForEach`. Try the following code.

```
 class Program
    {
        public static async Task GetStuffParallelForEach()
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
            Parallel.ForEach(data, async i =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000 * i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            });
        }

        public static async Task GetStuffForEachAsync()
        {
            var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
            await data.ForEachAsync(5, async i =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000 * i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            });

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //GetStuffParallelForEach().Wait(); // Finished printed before work is complete
            GetStuffForEachAsync().Wait(); // Finished printed after all work is done
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

if you run `GetStuffForEachAsync` the program waits for all work to finish. If you run `GetStuffParallelForEach`, the line `Finished` will be printed before the work is finished.