# Running Multiple Tasks in Parallel

Tags: c#

I have a list of proxies, each proxy goes to various sites and pulls the needed data from the sites. Currently it's doing this one at a time. But I'd like to have 10 - 20 tasks running at once so it's downloading from 20 sites in one go rather than just one.

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
private async Task<string> DownloadDataFromSite(string url)
{
     // (await) Do Work.
    return HTMLSourceCode;
}
```

I then loop through the proxies

```
foreach(Proxy p in proxies)
{
    string source = await DownloadDataFromSite(site);
}
```

Is `Parallel.ForEach` suitable for such a task? I've tried it, but the problem I'm having at the moment is not being able to `await`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to avoid awaiting in the foreach. The thing is that your `await` effectively blocks your execution. A better way might be something like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(proxies.Select(p => DownloadDataFromSite(site)));
```

This will mean you'll be awaiting all the tasks at once, which means the asynchronous I/O is going to happen in parallel. Note that if you're doing CPU work too, that's not going to really be parallelized.

The point is, asynchronous I/O (such as downloading a web page) doesn't require more threads to run in parallel. On the other hand, `Parallel.ForEach` is actually intended for CPU-bound work, rather than I/O bound work, and it does execute the code on multiple threads.

Comment: Interesting. Is `Select` intended to be used in this way? I assumed that `Select` is used to apply some type of transform method.

Comment: @JamesJeffery Well, that is a transformation method - it transforms an input parameter (`site`) into a `Task` :P

Answer (score 0):

`PArallel.ForEach` does not work well as it expects a synchronous lambda and giving it an asynchronous one basically causes it to return as soon as it starts. There is a way around it though, check this question out: [Is it OK to do some async/await inside some .NET Parallel.ForEach() code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729877/is-it-ok-to-do-some-async-await-inside-some-net-parallel-foreach-code/23730055#23730055)