# What is the fastest and most efficient ways to make a large number of C# WebRequests?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a list of URLs (thousands), I want to asynchronously get page data from each URL as fast as possible without putting extreme load on the CPU.

I have tried using threading but it still feels quite slow:

```
public static ConcurrentQueue<string> List = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(); //URL List (assume I added them already)

public static void Threading()
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) //100 threads
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Task));
        thread.Start();
    }
}

public static void Task()
{
    while(!(List.isEmpty))
    {
        List.TryDequeue(out string URL);
        //GET REQUEST HERE
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? I want to do this asynchronously but I can't figure out how to do it, and I don't want to sacrifice speed or CPU efficiency to do so.

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you read these;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737809/running-multiple-tasks-in-parallel

Comment: Every thread you create has it's own 1MB stack. You're allocating at least 100MB just to get started.

Comment: This rather depends on what you mean by large. However, at any scale I would consider large, the key would be to distribute the requesting across many machines, with many network interfaces, not across threads on one machine.

Comment: You can find some solutions in this question: [How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)

Answer (score -1):

You are best off using `HttpClient` which allows `async Task` requests.

Just store each task in a list, and `await` the whole list. To prevent too many requests at once, wait for any single one to complete if there are too many, and remove the completed one from the list.

```cs
const int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 100;

static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

public static async Task GetAllUrls(List<string> urls)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>(urls.Count);

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        if (tasks.Count == maxDegreeOfParallelism)    // this prevents too many requests at once
            tasks.Remove(await Task.WhenAny(tasks));

        tasks.Add(GetUrl(url));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task GetUrl(string url)
{
    using var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
    // handle response here
    var responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // whatever
    // do stuff etc
}
```

Comment: A few syntax errors. This code doesn't look tested.

Comment: Should be fixed now

Answer (score -1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
public static IObservable<(string url, string content)> GetAllUrls(List<string> urls) =>
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            hc =>
                from url in urls.ToObservable()
                from response in Observable.FromAsync(() => hc.GetAsync(url))
                from content in Observable.FromAsync(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
                select (url, content));
```

That allows you to consume the results in a couple of ways.

You can process them as they get produced:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    GetAllUrls(urlsx).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x.content));
```

Or you can get all of them produced and then await the full results:

```
(string url, string content)[] results = await GetAllUrls(urlsx).ToArray();
```